# Why does 点 mean "to light\to ignite" in certain compounds (such as in 点燃\点火\点灯)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, etymology

These are the only character's acceptations I really can't relate to, does anyone know why it's used with such meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

点(點), the original meaning is a small black spot. --> create a small spot --> use the pointed edge to touch something --> ignite by touching the wick.

Comment: I knew the original meaning of 点, but I didn't associeted it by extension with a wick. Is your interpretation based on some sources or on your own thesis? In the latter case, then why not therefore associete the black spot directly with the wick? Black maybe because when it burn it became black, or maybe because imbued with some derivatives of hydrocarbons to facilitate combustion (I don't know if this is historically plausubile). All this elaboration was because I find the connection between the last two steps of your thesis a bit farfetched.

Comment: Deng Siyi is correct.  The prototypical meaning of 點 is to ignite something using a small object burning at one end, like one makes a dot when writing a character or checking something on a list.